# Fitting gaussian and lorentz to data in python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian

I've loaded a set of data to python and think I've fit both Gaussian and Lorentz shapes, however I need it to print to values for each parameter stated and error associated and I don't know how to do this.

I'm a novice at programming so any help will be appreciated!

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np                                                
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                    
import pylab as p                                                  
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, leastsq                      
import math
from scipy.stats import norm

E,I = np.loadtxt('resonance_data.txt', unpack = True)

# Function to be fitted
def gauss(E, I0, E0, sigma):
    n = len(E)
    mean = sum(E*I)/sum(I)
    sigma = (np.sqrt(sum((E - mean)**2)/sum(I)))
    I0 = max(I)
    E0 = 31
    return I0* np.exp(-((E-E0)/sigma)**2)

sigmaerror = sigma - 28.01177

print sigmaerror

def lorentz(E,I0,E0,gamma):
    I0 = max(I)
    E0 = 31
    return I0*((gamma**2)/(((E-E0)**2)+gamma**2))

# Initialization parameters
init_vals = [45., 31., 33.]

best_vals, covar = curve_fit(gauss,E,I,p0=init_vals)
print best_vals

print curve_fit(gauss, E, I, p0=[max(I), mean, sigma])
print curve_fit(lorentz, E, I, p0=[max(I), mean, sigma])

plt.plot(E,I,'b+:',label='data')

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gauss,E,I,p0=[max(I), mean, sigma])
plt.plot(E,gauss(E,*popt),'r-',label='Gaussian')

popt,pcov = curve_fit(lorentz,E,I,p0=[max(I),mean,sigma])
plt.plot(E,lorentz(E,*popt), 'g', label='Lorentz')

plt.legend()
plt.title('Energy vs Intensity')
plt.xlabel('Energy')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.show()
print 'sigma =',sigma, 'error =', sigmaerror
print 'E0 = 34.22349966'
print 'I0 = 44.84743332'
```

Comment: The optimal parameters are stored in `best_vals`. It is very well explained in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simply print `popt` and `pcov`:

```
print(popt)
print(pcov)
```

They contain the parameters and covariances in the order you supply them to the model.